# Scale a repeatable bitmap in ImageView

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, imageview

I have a drawable `repeatable_stencil.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/stencil"
    android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

Then I use it in an ImageView like this:

```
   <ImageView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/repeatable_stencil"
    />
```

The way my imageview is setup, it is supposed to fill its parent with the `repeatable_stencil`. It does the job, but incorrectly.

The `stencil` image is about `2500 x 4000` in pixels. But, when it is used like how I did above, the bitmap is automatically scaled, and the `stencil` image is super zoomed.

I want to scale it down to custom dimensions.

Comment: Just curious. Why are you using an image with such high resolution if you just want to have it tiled repeatedly. Wouldn't it make sense to use a small sized image?

Comment: @Froyo so the image has a lot of small and distinct features, unlike a simple texture. It looks like small doodles on paper. I could use a small sized image, but it would look pixelated due to the fine lines on the image. WIth high-res I could make sure that there won't be any pixelation. I only want it to be tiled repeatedly, cause, it'll be displayed inside a nested scroll view. The list could grow and i'd *theoretically* never run out of background image